# tags & notes are not working!

Tags: tags

Hi fellow sharepoint devs!

I'm running a Windows 2012 server with a windows sql 2012. Furthermore, im running Sharepoint 2013 on it. It seems, that I have an issue with the tags & notes feature. 
When I'm logged in as administrator the button is disabled, sadly it's always disabled.

Where can I enable this feature?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I figured it out with help from the following links:

- [SharePoint 2013: How to Configure Managed Metadata Service](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12713.sharepoint-2013-how-to-configure-managed-metadata-service.aspx)
- [If this error occurs: 
  The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available.](http://sharepointroot.com/2011/01/11/the-managed-metadata-service-or-connection-is-currently-not-available/)
- [How to Restart IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms957500%28v=cs.70%29.aspx)